# setInterval is not working in YUI

Tags: javascript, html, yui

I am trying to use SetInterval and clearInterval in YUI

The code is written so it will create element every second and on mouse hover of div it should stop creating element.

http://jsbin.com/awadek/5

Please let me know what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an anonymous function as a handler to "mouseover".  Otherwise, Javascript will attempt to evaluate and call the return from clearInterval (in this case, an integer!).  The following code will work:

```
 YUI().use("console", "console-filters", "substitute", "node-event-simulate",
   function(Y) {
     console.log("YUI is ready");

     var doSomething = function(e) {
       Y.one("#seconds").append("<p>I am number four</p>");
     };

     IntervalId = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);
     //Notice the anonymous function below:
     Y.one("#clearInt").on('mouseover', function() { clearInterval( IntervalId ) });
 });
```

Here is your [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/awadek/10), ftfy.  Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, while using IntervalId = setInterval(doSomething, 1000); its not working, and when using without id [setInterval(doSomething, 1000);] its working. why so?

Comment: Have you looked at my updated [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/awadek/11)?  It seems to be working just fine with InternalId and the anonymous function.  Why your original example would or would not work based on IntervalID is a more complicated question (it has to do with *calling* an integer object versus an undefined object).